# Git: permission denied? Can clone but can't push

Tags: git, ssh

So I get:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have a second git setup in my ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host github-work
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile work
```

Cloning went fine via SSH, but I can't push? The ~/.ssh/work and .pub files exist, I've made the key, added it etc how can I get `git push` to also use this?

`.git/config` indeed uses `github-work`

Comment: When you cloned, did you use `github-work` or `github.com`? You should be able to see with `git remote -v`. Also, when you do `ssh -T git@github.com`, which identity does it show?

Comment: fetch and push seem to be using git@github-work:username/repo.git. `ssh -T git@github.com` authenticates with my non-work account, ssh -T git@github-work says permission denied.

Comment: Does your real `~/.ssh/config` file have a full path for the IdentityFile value?

Comment: @JimRedmond that's the real one, work and work.pub both exist under ~/.ssh/ but it doesn't have an absolute path in the config no.

Comment: It needs a path, but `~` is supported for that parameter. You should be able to test with `ssh -Ti ~/.ssh/work git@github-work`; if that is able to connect, then you should change `IdentityFile work` to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work`.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling my comment into an answer: The `IdentityFile` parameter in your `~/.ssh/config` needs a path to the file; it doesn't assume the identity is in `~/.ssh`. The config file supports use of the tilde shorthand, so `~/.ssh/work` should be a valid path here.

It may also be worthwhile to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to that stanza, as it will cause your ssh-agent to try only the specified identity or identities for the named host.

Comment: Can confirm providing an absolute path doesn't make a difference. It just attempts to push with the non work account.